# JQuery animation of image

Tags: animation

Ok, I was doing a simple JQuery animation. When a user will click on an image,it will move to the left by 1000px. Here is the code below:

```
function cloud2 () {    
$('#cloud2').animate({left:'1000px'},40000);
        setTimeout(cloud2,2000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cloud2').click(function() {
   cloud2();
});
});
```

Very nice nothing is wrong, all is working like a BOSS! When the image reaches 1000px, it stops. All good! What I want now, is to replace the image with another image once it stops when it completes the 1000px animation. How to do that? For example, once it stops, the image changes to another one, let's say image2.jpg for instance.

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

animate() has an event for ending animation.
For example you have something like:

`<img src="image1.jpg" id="myimg">`

```
function moveimg() {
    $('#myimg').animate({left: '1000px'}, 40000, function() {
        $('#myimg').attr('src', 'image2.jpg');
    });
}

setTimeout("moveimg()", "2000")
```

Comment: Does not work at all.. The first image just stopped and does not change